# system call not opening .jar

Tags: c++, visual-c++, jar

I am trying to open a .jar file, which is located at C:\Users\MyUser\ThisProgram.jar. I want to open it directly, using a system call, instead of having to use terminal manually. My current code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str2 = "java -jar C:\\Users\\MyUser\\MyProgram.jar";
    const char* cmd2 = str2.c_str();
    system(cmd2);
}
```

I am getting an error that says "Unable to access jar file ThisProgram.jar". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does the command `java -jar C:\Users\MyUser\MyProgram.jar` work correctly when you run in a terminal? Also, `MyProgram.jar` or `ThisProgram.jar`?

Comment: Yes, it does. The actual name is SmartBar.jar, i was just trying to keep it easy by not using the names and just saying what it was